# What is the number of elements in $\{A=(a_{ij}) \in Gl_n(\mathbb{F}_q):a_{11}=1\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be the finite field with $q$ elements. I want to calculate the number of elements of the set $S=\{A=(a_{ij}) \in Gl_n(\mathbb{F}_q):a_{11}=1\}.$

We know that $|Gl_n(\mathbb{F}_q)|=(q^n-1)(q^n-q)\cdots(q^n-q^{n-1}).$ Trying to define some group homomorphism from $Gl_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ to $\mathbb{F}_q^{\times}$ whose kernel is $S,$ but failed to do so. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is probably dumb but my guess is that this contains the same amount of elements $S=\{A=(a_{ij}) \in Gl_n(\mathbb{F}_q):a_{11}=u\}$ for any $u\in\mathbb F_q$ and these are disjoints sets that partition $Gl_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ hence they each have a fraction $\frac{1}{q}$ of the elements of the later. Hence $\frac{1}{q}(q^n-1)(q^n-q)\dots (q^n-q^{n-1})$. This seems a bit simple though and this may not be true for $u=0$ for some reasons unknown to me.

Comment: Follow up question on that : does this set contains the same amount of elements as any set of the form $\{A=(a_{ij}) \in Gl_n(\mathbb{F}_q):f(A)=0\}$ where $f(A)$ is a non constant linear function of the elements of $A$ ? and what if we have several linear constraints ?

Comment: Recall the proof of the $\left|\operatorname{GL}_n\left(\mathbb{F}_q\right)\right|$ formula, where you build your matrix column by column. Now adapt it to the $a_{11} = 1$ requirement.

Comment: @darij grinberg: So will it be $q^{n-1}(q^n-q)\cdots (q^n-q^{n-1})$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.

Comment: Yah I was thinking something silly. Thanks.